# iOS push notification from azure are not delivered

Tags: ios, node.js, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

In the past I have developed several iOS apps which use Windows Azure Mobile Services in NodeJS as back-end.

Almost all of those apps must receive push notifications and I used the push service embedded in the Mobile Services to fulfill this requirement.

Now, I'm developing a new application with the same requirement. I was confident that everything would go fine: indeed notifications to Android and Windows Phone work perfectly.
But iOS notifications are not delivered! Moreover, the backend does not show any error: I suppose that the tokens and the push payloads are ok...

My greatest fear is that something is changed with the new iOS 8.

Somebody else is suffering from the same problem? Which solution have you adopted (external push services, hub notification services, etc).

I have to keep Windows Azure in NodeJS as back-end since it is almost finished... the push are the last requirement I need to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure how old your older Mobile Services are but Mobile Services changed from using it's own backend push engine to using one powered by Notification Hubs.  Have you taken this into account and walked through the latest tutorial on doing push with iOS?  (this is the latest tutorial for iOS and Mobile Services push using the built in Notification Hubs: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/).

Comment: I've had success sending push to iOS8 devices using NH w/Mobile Services.  Can you check if you are using NH or legacy mode on your service?  Also let us know if you are using the SDK to register your device (and if so, which one: native, Xamarin.iOS, or JS)

Comment: @Chris: my old services uses the old mechanism to send push (no NH). But the tutorial you suggest is the one I've followed twice yesterday, without any success.

Comment: @philipv: I was using the legacy mode to send push. Honestly, I followed the tutorial with a new app, and so by using the integrated notification hub. But the push were still not delivered. I'm registering my app from JS... Anyway, I built a simple console application in C# to try to send the push and it worked. So honestly... I think that there is a problem between Windows Azure and iOS: I can successfully deliver the push notifications to both WindowsPhone and Android from Windows Azure.

Comment: When you upload your APNS cert to the right hub, are you sure you're picking the right environment, I've ran into that before because it's defaulted to prod where the OLD way was defaulted to testing / sandbox.  Are you seeing any errors logged in your hubs dashboard?

Comment: No... The problem is that I can't see any error in the hub dashboard! However, I solved the problem by creating my own push server in .NET... I hosted it into Windows Azure, I used the same certificate I had uploaded in the mobile services notification hub and my server works wonderfully! ;)